# Is there any function to check if a directory or folder exist in PHP?

Tags: php, directory

I want to check if there is a directory exist or not before uploading a file.

If the directory does not exist return FALSE.

Does is_dir do the work?

Comment: You know, the documentation answers your question exactly. It takes 20 seconds to check.

Comment: I agree with Yacoby, PHP has an amazing manual, you should learn to use it and love it.

Comment: Found this sentence in the FAQ: 'No question is too trivial or too "newbie".'

Comment: I am not saying that the question shouldn't have been asked, I just wanted to point out that often it is easier and faster to use the documentation.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that it is correct or not. Getting an expert idea is more important than just reading. Thanks for minus, it is very encouraging for a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[is_dir()](http://php.net/is_dir) well check if the first argument is a directory and [is_file()](http://php.net/is_file) will check if the first argument is a file.

They both return true if the dir/file exists, and false if not.

Answer (score 3):

Yes is_dir() is the solution. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you wanted to check that "etc/data/images/" is a directory you could use:

```
$dir = "etc/data/images/";  //First specify the directory you want to check existence of.

    if(is_dir($dir)){ //The 'is_dir' function does the checking.

     echo "Yes, $dir is a directory.";

}else{//If 'is_dir' returns false, the following will be ran:

    echo 'No that is not a directory...';
}
```